# Is there a command in EWW for copying the URL of the current webpage?

Tags: eww

In org capture, it's possible to capture the URL of a webpage in EWW, and then store the link in an .org file.

My question is:

Is there a general way to copy the URL of the current page into the clipboard/kill ring, so that one can later paste the URL into any mode, not just into org-mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> tells you about the major mode and its keybindings, where we can see:

```
w        eww-copy-page-url
```

Which will "Copy the URL of the current page into the kill ring."

<kbd>w</kbd> is usefully similar to the standard <kbd>M-w</kbd> for copying text, so should be easy to remember on that account.